# How do I update Visual Studio 2019's HTML validation rules for Razor/cshtml to recognize <dialog>?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 does not correctly validate HTML5 `<dialog>` elements: it rejects all child elements (such as `<div>`) even though [the Content Model of `<dialog>` expressly allows them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

[image]

As Visual Studio 2019 uses different HTML validation rules for Razor `.cshtml` than for the older WebForms-oriented HTML editor tools the "Tag Specific Options" button under `Tools > Options` doesn't let me make changes to the XML/SGML schema used for the HTML validation rules.

How can I configure Visual Studio 2019, manually if necessary, to validate HTML5 correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a user-friendly way to override VS's HTML schema.  You can edit the files yourself, but they'll be overwritten the next time you update your VS build.

If you wish to attempt it, the files are located at `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML` with most elements defined in the `html.xsd` file.

The best way to get it fixed is to report the issue through Visual Studio Feedback so that we can fix it.  (Sometimes this takes a while, but I'm trying to get the team to prioritize schema issues.  Also, if you can get enough votes on the item, it does internally bump up the priority as well.)

Source: I'm the new owner for these schemas, and am trying to catch up after several years of neglect.

[edit:]
I've just submitted a fix, it will ship in the 16.9 wave.  If you want to hotfix it yourself, you should be able to replace lines 585-602 with this:

```
  <xsd:element name="dialog" vs:block="true" vs:description="109">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:group ref="flowContent" />
      </xsd:choice>
      <xsd:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributeGroup" />
      <xsd:attribute name="open" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the 16.9 update - I've since encountered another schema error: the schema needs to be updated to allow for headings, like `<h2>` and `<h3>` inside `<details><summary>`. I'd have filed a bug for this but I'm having trouble logging-in to my MSA right now.... and opening `windows.xsd` gives me warnings about global attributes in the Error List window, erk.

Comment: (Need to post a new comment reply due to 5-minute lockout), but just to clarify:  `html.xsd` _seems correct_ (via `flowContent`), but even-so I get VS validation warnings saying that "Element `h2` cannot be nested within element `summary`". Weird...

Comment: @Dai which version of VS are you using?  I'm trying it now on the latest builds and I don't see any warnings for `<details><summary><h2></h2></summary></details>`.

Comment: I'm running `16.11.24`, here's the squiggles: https://imgur.com/lr4RhKt - this is in an `.ascx` file, if that matters - but I thought the Razor (MVC 3), Razor V4, and WebForms HTML editors used the same schemas? The HTML Editing Toolbar says I have the "DOCTYPE: HTML5" schema selected btw. - the SHA1 of my `Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\html.xsd` is `9400E781C7BE38122C2BE2C07F1C13142E9E6B27` - does that match yours? (hmm, what about `Packages\Schemas\html\html_5.xsd`?)

Comment: Ah, the WebForms (ASPX/ASCX) editor is completely different from the Razor v3 editor, which is (now) completely different from the Razor editor for .NET (Core).  You're right, the problem is in the other schema you found (html_5.xsd).

Comment: I filed a ticket on your behalf here.  It's unlikely to be fixed in 16.x though, you'll have to move to 17.x or make the fix yourself. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/HTML:-h2-not-allowed-in-summary-tag-in-W/10288438